# Rails fetch images from different months

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, search

Iam a Rails developer and working on a project which needs to a show collection set of different images. I want to implement an algorithm where I want to fetch **images** in different **timespan** , for instance, 30% images from **current month** and 20% images from **previous month** and so on and shuffle them all together and create a set and then show it on the website. Thus it makes me to target **created_at** attribute for **Image** model and fetch images on the basis of the creation date.

I looked for various possible solutions. One of them is **Thinking Sphinx**. As per the [doc](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#fieldweights) you can give **field weight** to an attribute. But my problem is I want to give weightage within the attribute i.e. 30 % to first month, 20% to second month. So I didnt find it a good solution.

Next I thought to achieve the same using **scopes**

*Image model*

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :current_month, where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", Time.now, 1.month.ago).shuffle.take(6)
  scope :previous_month, where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", 1.month.ago, 2.month.ago).shuffle.take(5)
  scope :last_month, where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", 2.month.ago, 3.month.ago).shuffle.take(4)
end
```

*Image Controller*

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  @total_images = Image.current_month + Image.previous_month + Image.last_month
end
```

But this fetches the same set of Images for each request. Whereas I need **different images** everytime a request is made. Moreover this will make my website's **performance** really down since a single request hits my database so many times.

Please guide me a better and correct way to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This reminds me of an issue I had, when the time was cached during the rails startup. Does the three scopes return different images, but always the same in each scope?

Comment: Yeah the 3 scopes return me different images but each scope always return the same set of images. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Have a look into your console, and look at the sql queries that are actual retrieving the content. Are the time parameters changing?

Comment: You should try Solr with Sunspot.

Comment: No the time parameters are'nt changing. What can be done then?